# Python 3 use kwargs to replace nested dictionary values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion

I've scoured documentation and used the help of many teammates, but have not been able to figure out how to replace a dictionary with values provided as kwargs through (in my case) a test function:

Template dictionary:

```
{
    "id": "id_1234",
    "integer_value": 1234,
    "level_one": {
        "id": 1234,
        "foo": "true",
        "list_one": [],
        "list_two": [
            522
        ],
        "url": "http://google.com",
        "level_two": {
            "thing_one": {
                "yes": "false",
                "no": "false"
            },
            "thing_two": {
                "yes": "false",
                "no": "false"
            }
        },
        "another_field": "true",
        "bar": 15000
    }
}
```

Recursive dictionary function:

```
def update_dictionary(template_dict, **kwargs):
for k, v in kwargs.items():
    print(v)
    print(isinstance(v, collections.Mapping))
    if isinstance(v, collections.Mapping):
        print("This is the k value")
        print(k)
        template_dict[k] = update_dictionary(template_dict.get(k, {}), v)
    else:
        print("We're going into the else now")
        template_dict[k] = v
return template_dict
```

I got the above function from another forum on here, but it doesn't seem to work when passing kwargs. isinstance check turns out to be False for any fields that are not in the first level of the nested dictionary. Any help is appreciated!

Line in test where the kwargs are passed:

```
new_dict = update_dictionary(template_dict, another_field = 'false', integer_value=12345)
```

Comment: Keys will never be an instance of `collections.Mapping`, at least,not until you implement a hashable mapping. You probably mean `isinstance(v, collections.Mapping)`

Comment: Ah, yes, that was a typo on my behalf. (v, collections.Mapping) also returns False for all nested dictionary keys in this case.

Comment: Also, you need to keep passing the `**kwargs` ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you need to keep passing the `kwargs`, or else everything past the first level won't have anything to replace! Here's a quick-and-dirty demonstration:

```
def update_dict(d, **kwargs):
    new = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            new[k] = update_dict(v, **kwargs)
        else:
            new[k] = kwargs.get(k, v)
    return new
```

In action:

```
In [16]: template
Out[16]:
{'id': 'id_1234',
 'integer_value': 1234,
 'level_one': {'another_field': 'true',
  'bar': 15000,
  'foo': 'true',
  'id': 1234,
  'level_two': {'thing_one': {'no': 'false', 'yes': 'false'},
   'thing_two': {'no': 'false', 'yes': 'false'}},
  'list_one': [],
  'list_two': [522],
  'url': 'http://google.com'}}

In [17]: update_dict(template, another_field = 'false', integer_value=12345)
Out[17]:
{'id': 'id_1234',
 'integer_value': 12345,
 'level_one': {'another_field': 'false',
  'bar': 15000,
  'foo': 'true',
  'id': 1234,
  'level_two': {'thing_one': {'no': 'false', 'yes': 'false'},
   'thing_two': {'no': 'false', 'yes': 'false'}},
  'list_one': [],
  'list_two': [522],
  'url': 'http://google.com'}}
```

And again:

```
In [19]: update_dict(template, another_field = 'false', integer_value=12345, no='FOO')
Out[19]:
{'id': 'id_1234',
 'integer_value': 12345,
 'level_one': {'another_field': 'false',
  'bar': 15000,
  'foo': 'true',
  'id': 1234,
  'level_two': {'thing_one': {'no': 'FOO', 'yes': 'false'},
   'thing_two': {'no': 'FOO', 'yes': 'false'}},
  'list_one': [],
  'list_two': [522],
  'url': 'http://google.com'}}
```

Note, this implementation *returns an entirely new `dict`*, which is what I assume you wanted, since `template` is a template, and you wrote:

```
new_dict = update_dictionary(template_dict, another_field = 'false', integer_value=12345)
```

But if you *actually* wanted to modify in-place, you can simply change to:

```
def update_dict(d, **kwargs):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            update_dict(v, **kwargs)
        else:
            d[k] = kwargs.get(k, v)
```

I would go with the non-in-place version... Note, you can do this with a cheeky one-liner, although, I wouldn't recommend it:

```
def update_dict(d, **kwargs):
    return {k:update_dict(v, **kwargs) if isinstance(v, dict) else kwargs.get(k,v) for k,v in d.items()}
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I do in fact need to modify in-place, so I used your suggestion, and replaced (v, dict) with (v, collections.Mapping) since I have some other data types that would need to be modified as well. I was checking against the kwargs this whole time rather than the template dictionary! It all makes sense now